# To what extent may I customize a demiplane?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, planes

For example, say I want to cast *demiplane* and make it zero gravity.
Can I do this? The rules do not say anything about the *demiplane*'s gravity
so this seems like it could be valid but I am not sure.

Comment: The demiplane spell is on PHB page 231, you may want to add that to your question as my edit has been rejected though I'm not sure if the community would consider that an improvement to your question.

Comment: You also may want to clarify that you are the caster of said demiplane in your title as it currently reads this can easily be misunderstood as a gming question before you read the body. Though the community also thinks that this is not relevant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's total DM discretion, but yes, you could. The only direct thing that says about its main, base rules is that it has to be wood or stone, it's empty when created, 30 ft in all directions, and only allows up to Medium creatures to pass through the door to it without having to make a skill check.

> [from the [Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spells#Demiplane), pg. 231]
>
> The door is large enough to allow Medium creatures to pass through unhindered. When opened, the door leads to a demiplane that appears to be an empty room 30 feet in each dimension, made of wood or stone.

Other than that, it's fair game as long as the DM allows you to do that.

Answer (score 10):

### Possibly to any extent (including zero-gravity), possibly to very little

The *demiplane* spell only specifies a handful of rules:

> a demiplane that appears to be an empty room 30 feet in each dimension, made of wood or stone

Anything beyond this is open to interpretation by you and your GM. There are details on the limitations and qualities of demiplanes in the *Player's Handbook* Appendix C, "The Planes of Existence":

> Demiplanes are small extradimensional spaces with their own unique rules. They are pieces of reality that don’t seem to fit anywhere else... They may exist naturally, as a fold of existing reality that has been pinched off from the rest of the multiverse, or as a baby universe growing in power...

With so little details, it will be entirely GM dependent what the limits of your particular demiplane are.